# Python: How to convert a string containing hex bytes to a hex string

Tags: python, string, hex

I'm thinking binascii is the module I'm looking for, but I can't quite seem to get the exact results for which I am looking.

Here's what I want to do.  I want to convert:

```
>>> s = '356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab'
>>> print len(s)
40
```

to

```
>>> hs = '\x35\x6a\x19\x2b\x79\x13\xb0\x4c\x54\x57\x4d\x18\xc2\x8d\x46\xe6\x39\x54\x28\xab'
>>> print len(hs)
20
```

Any Pythonistas know of a cool (or, frankly, functional) way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In **all versions of Python**, you can use the function 
[`binascii.a2b_hex()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_hex) (also known as [`binascii.unhexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify)):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> s = '356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab'
>>> binascii.a2b_hex(s)
'5j\x19+y\x13\xb0LTWM\x18\xc2\x8dF\xe69T(\xab'
```

In **Python 3.x**, you can use [`bytes.fromhex(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex).

In **Python 2.x**, you can use the `hex` str-to-str codec:

```
>>> s.decode("hex")
'5j\x19+y\x13\xb0LTWM\x18\xc2\x8dF\xe69T(\xab'
```

The codec internally calls `binascii.a2b_hex()`.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for, and it was in the string class waiting for me.  Thanks, Sven!

Comment: You can also do s.decode("hex").upper() to get uppercase if that is important.

Comment: would you mind providing a Python 3.x version since this is the accepted answer (and will likely be so forevers)

Comment: @Marc The answer actually already included the Python 3 version without explicitly stating so – now made explicit.

Comment: Now you can do `bytes.fromhex('356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab')`

Comment: @Marc As stated before, the last line works on Python 3.  The solution you found is nice as well.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for the feedback – I've tried to clarify the answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

With `binascii` module:

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> s = '356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab'
>>> unhexlify(s)
'5j\x19+y\x13\xb0LTWM\x18\xc2\x8dF\xe69T(\xab'
```

Comment: `unhexlify()` is only another name for `a2b_hex()` [binascii Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_hex)