# How do I encode hexadecimal to base64 in python?

Tags: python, base64

If I try to do:

```
from base64 import b64encode
b64encode('ffffff')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    base64.b64encode('ffffff')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Because it said bytes-like object I then tried this:

```
b64encode(bytes('ffffff'))
```

Which failed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    b64encode(bytes('ffffff'))
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Finally, using the `.encode('utf-8')` function:

```
b64encode('ffffff'.encode('utf-8'))
```

With incorrect output `b'ZmZmZmZm'`, the correct base64 encoding is `////`.

I already know how to decode b64 to hex so don't say how to do that.

Edit: This question got flagged for being the same as converting hex strings to hex bytes.  This involves base64.

Comment: `bytes('fffff', 'UTF-8')` is what you're looking for. But I don't think `'ffffff'` does what you think it does, it's not the same as `'\xff\xff\xff'`.

Comment: It didn't work, just returned `b'ZmZmZmZm'` again.
(Assuming you meant: `b64encode(bytes('ffffff', 'utf-8'))`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to convert a string containing hex bytes to a hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824319/python-how-to-convert-a-string-containing-hex-bytes-to-a-hex-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fully go from the string `ffffff` to base64 of the hex value, you need to run it through some encoding and decoding, using the `codecs` module:

```
import codecs
# Convert string to hex
hex = codecs.decode('ffffff', 'hex')
# Encode as base64 (bytes)
codecs.encode(hex, 'base64')
```

For an odd-length string like `0xfffff` you need to put a zero at the beginning of the hex string (`0x0fffff`), otherwise python will give you an error.

Comment: You can also go through `struct.pack('B', int('ff',16))`

Comment: Yes - though if you're pulling in `codecs` for base64, it seems 'neater' to me to use it for both parts.

Comment: Absolutely agree, there's nothing fancy about going manual to solve this. But hopefully it teaches someone why and how codecs work. So I threw in a small explanation of how hex works.

Comment: @EricJin, you could append using modolus to get the correct length. `s = s + '0'*(len(s)%2)`. Which would only append `0` if the length of the string is not equal to a round number. However, this will give you inaccurate results since you probably don't know if you need to append the `0` at the start or end of your string? My solution works on odd lengths as well. However it simply ignores the odd number that isn't complete. So beware of that.

Comment: Using `codecs.encode` always seems to stick a newline character at the end of the result for me, but `base64.b64encode` does not. H/T [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40454177/2829764)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to using codecs.
This one is a bit less readable, but works great and hopefully teaches you how codecs, hex and integers work. *(word of caution, works on odd lengths, but will ignore the odd byte-string-representation)*

```
import struct
s = 'ffffff'
b''.join([struct.pack('B', int(''.join(x), 16)) for x in zip(s[0::2], s[1::2])])
```

Which should give you `b'\xff\xff\xff'`.

Your main problem is probably that you think `'ffffff'` represents the values `255, 255, 255`. Which they don't. They're still in a string format with the letters ff. Subsequently you need to parse/convert the string representation of hex, into actual hex. We can do this by first passing the string through `int()` which can intemperate hex in string representation format.

You will need to convert each pair of `ff` individually by doing `int('ff', 16)` which tells Python to intemperate the string as a base-16 integer (hex-numbers).

And then convert that integer into a bytes like object representing that integer. That's where [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) comes in. It's meant for exactly this.

```
struct.pack('B', 255) # 255 is given to us by int('ff', 16)
```

Essentially, `'B'` tells Python to pack the value 255 into a 1-byte-object, in this case, that gives us `b'\xff'` which is your end goal. Now, do this for every 2-pair of letters in your original data.

---

This is more of a manual approach where you'll iterate over 2 characters in the string at a time, and use the above description to bundle them into what you expect them to be. Or just use codecs, either way works.

Expanded version of the above oneliner:

```
import struct
hex_string = 'ffffff'
result = b''
for pair in zip(hex_string[0::2], hex_string[1::2]):
    value = int(''.join(pair), 16)
    result += struct.pack('B', value)
```

At the very least, I hope this explains how hex works on a practical level. And how the computer interpenetrates hour humanly readable version of bits and bytes.